# New Notebook is extrem slow after clean Win10 install

Tags: boot, performance, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-core-i7

Okey so my problem is, i bought the Acer Predator Helios 300. 
It came with the endless os. And after installing Win 8.1 ( which said i couldnt use Win 8.1 bc it wouldnt support my CPU -> I7 7th Gen) i swapped to Win10. 
After that i reinstalled the whole thing again, deleted all partitions and setup all drivers again ( not in this order).
But now my boot time is at 2.43 min. And opening things like Chrome, Virtual Studio or Steam takes also quite some time. Nothing like 2 min but more like 10-15 sec.
Do anyone has some advice or had some similar experiences? 
Thanks in Advance.

P.s after i tried a game League. It took 5 min to load the game but ingame i have 240 fps & 20 ms ... so is it the cpu?

Comment: MBR or GPT?  Update your question.

Comment: @Ramhound it's GPT

Comment: I wanted to ask a comment but cannot until my reputation is higher? anyway.. 1. is the HDD the 128GB SSD? - can you download an SSD health utility and run some checks. 2. have you updated the motherboard BIOS yet? 3. download HIRENS BOOT CD version 10.2 and make a bootable USB. You may need to hunt around to find it. http://www.hirensbootcd.org/hbcd-v102/ Run PC-Check 6.21: Easy to use hardware tests. do the 20 mins stress test. If it crashes at any point DURING the test, you may have failing hardware, such as motherboard or SSD. hope that helps!